# C++ print elements with data from object array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am currently working with object arrays in c++. I have a Book object array filled with data from a datafile, and I need to loop through the array of Book objects and print each of the elements that contain book data, one per line. When I print it out, there are items in the list that are "empty" with no title, no ISBN, a price of 0 and a quantity of 0. How can I get it to only print out the elements that contain data?

Comment: Use an `if()` statement to check whether the object has values.

Comment: Why don't you use `std::vector` so you only put valid books into the vector?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. It'd be great if you could provide an [mcve] so we and future users can see exactly what you mean, instead of only reading a description!

Comment: Preparing a minimal complete example isn't just for our convenience, either; you're quite likely to discover the bug along the way. And you don't have to work backward to it, you can also use the same principle forward as you code, developing each new piece of functionality in isolation before hooking it into the whole. (For some reason they never teach these things in CompSci courses.)

Comment: Is this a school homework or job task as for the first I can provide you with private lessons and for second I can solve your problem for the minimum hourly wage. But joking aside we need to get some code to work with if you want your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a range-based `for` loop with a check to see if the book object is empty:

```
Book books[255];
// or
std::vector<Book> books;

for(const auto& book : books) {
  if(!book.isEmpty()) {
    std::cout << book.print() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

As @Barmar said, it'd be better if you use a `std::vector` and only add a new `Book` when you know that it's not an empty object - then you have a container of valid books and you can forgo the `isEmpty()` check.

If your `Book` object doesn't have a really straightforward internal way of knowing if it's empty or not, rather than adding an `isEmpty()` member function to the interface, it's better to have a **non-member non-friend** convenience function to check if the book is empty:

```
class Book {
public:
  std::string title() const;
  std::string author() const;
  std::string isbn() const;
  // simpler is better... it's already getting cluttered...
  ...
};

// you don't need to be a member of Book to know if a Book is empty! 
bool isEmpty(const Book& book) {
  return book.title().empty() && book.author().empty() && book.isbn().empty();
}
```

(That's a bit of a contrived example - it could be reasonably assumed that a Book is empty if its title is empty.)

```
for(const auto& book : books) {
  if(!isEmpty(book)) {
    std::cout << book.print() << std::endl;
  }
}
```

A more advanced technique would be to put the `isEmpty(Book)` convenience function into the same namespace as the `Book` object. But that's not likely to matter on small projects.

(98% of this post is regurgitated from Scott Meyer's Effective C++ 3rd Edition, ISBN 0-321-33487-6, price £n/a, quantity 1)